# React.PropType with two possible shapes

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

**Background**: I'm trying to specify a prop type for a dimension spec where I can either specify an explicit value, or a min and max value to evaluate. This will be used by an image component that will evaluate if the image is an acceptable height and width for user generated input.

> The abstract goal is to have a React props value resolve to one of two possible shapes.

---

### Each of the shapes work on their own

an *explicit value* for width would have this shape:

```
{
    width: PropTypes.shape({
        value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        error: PropTypes.string
    })
}
```

a *min and max* value would have this shape:

```
{
    width: PropTypes.shape({
        min: {
            value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            error: PropTypes.string
        }, max: {
            value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            error: PropTypes.string
        }
    })
}
```

*EDIT: As pointed out in the accepted answer, there is a bug in this block that I did not catch.  For some reason it was not giving me a run-time error, but this is not a working example of nested shapes, see the answer for the correct syntax.*

If I try either of these methods and the properties match, everything works as expected *so I can safely assume errors are coming from the code below*.

---

### What does not work

I tried using an optionalUnion as seen in the [**React typechecking documentation**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) via **PropTypes.oneOfType** with the syntax below.

```
{
    width: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.shape({
            value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            error: PropTypes.string
        }), PropTypes.shape({
            min: {
                value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                error: PropTypes.string
            }, max: {
                value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                error: PropTypes.string
            }
        })
    ])
}
```

When I try this, I get the response

`Warning: Failed propType: checker is not a function Check the render method of 'MyParentContainer'.`

If I use either shape without the `PropTypes.oneOfType` method, no complaints in the debugger, everything runs as expected.  `PropTypes.oneOf` throws a seemingly worse error:

`warning.js:45Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop 'dimensions.width' of value '[object Object]' supplied to 'MyComponent', expected one of [null,null]. Check the render method of 'MyParentContainer'.`

Does anyone know if this syntax is off or is this a limitation of PropTypes.oneOfType?  Is there a standard solution to this kind of problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`PropTypes.shape` is not recursive, you have to repeat it for substructures, e.g.

```
width: PropTypes.shape({
    min: PropTypes.shape({
        value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        error: PropTypes.string
    }).isRequired,
    max: PropTypes.shape({
        value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        error: PropTypes.string
    }).isRequired
})
```

Therefore, the entire validator should be:

```
const propTypes = {
    width: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.shape({
            value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            error: PropTypes.string
        }),
        PropTypes.shape({
            min: PropTypes.shape({
                value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                error: PropTypes.string
            }).isRequired,
            max: PropTypes.shape({
                value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                error: PropTypes.string
            }).isRequired
        })
    ])
};
```

Also, I really recommend to use variables to increase readability and prevent code duplication:

```
const valueType = PropTypes.shape({
    value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    error: PropTypes.string
});

const propTypes = {
     width: PropTypes.oneOfType([
         valueType,
         PropTypes.shape({
             min: valueType.isRequired,
             max: valueType.isRequired
         })
     ])
 };
```

Comment: Man... Should have caught that, thank you.  It's a bit odd I didn't get a run-time error from the first two examples.  I hear you on creating the PropType constants, I was originally using them, but I backed out to keep the example focused on the problem I'm having.  Great example.